# How to make a new sentence from "My mother forced me to eat the eggs." where the eggs become the subject?

Tags: passive-voice

> A: My mother forced me to eat the eggs.
>
> B: I was forced to eat the eggs by my mother.

I want to make the eggs as the subject for a new sentence. My attempt is as follows. I think it is wrong but what is the correct one?

> C1: The eggs were eaten by me whom was forced by my mother.
>
> C2: The eggs were eaten by me whom my mother forced.

## Edit:

To make it more general, let I change the sentence as follows.

> a: My mother forced me to break the eggs.
>
> b: I was forced to break the eggs by my mother.

I want to make the eggs as the subject for a new sentence. My attempt is as follows. I think it is wrong but what is the correct one?

> c1: The eggs were broken by me whom was forced by my mother.
>
> c2: The eggs were broken by me whom my mother forced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The eggs were what my mother forced me to eat.

Comment: I think this is the most awkward sentence I've ever upvoted.

Comment: Surely there was a way to include even _less_ content in this answer.